# Access and update PFObject from TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am new to iOS coding, and Parse, but have a question. I have created a table view which accesses the PFObjects and displays them correctly. My problem is that I have a button in each cell (a like button) and I want it to update the specific PFObject when pressed. How do I access it?

```
class chinTwoTimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var timelineData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func loadData() {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "ChinTwos")


    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in

        if let objects = findTimelineData.findObjects() as? [PFObject] {

            if error == nil{
                for object in objects{
                    let chinTwo:PFObject = object as PFObject
                    self.timelineData.addObject(chinTwo)
                }

                let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:ChinTwoTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChinTwoTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let chinTwo:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject


    var myVar:Int = chinUp.objectForKey("likeCount") as! Int
    cell.countLabel.text = String(myVar)

    cell.nameLabel.text = chinUp.objectForKey("name") as? String
    cell.bodyText.text = chinUp.objectForKey("body") as! String

    cell.bodyText.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 18)
    cell.bodyText.textAlignment = .Center

    return cell
}

@IBAction func likeButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // This is where I am lost.
```

}

If you need more information to help, let me know, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected IndexPath using `convertPoint` then get the PFObject from the array.

```
@IBAction func likeButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // This is where I am lost. 
        var senderPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self?.tableView)
       var indexPath = self?.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(senderPoint)
       let chinTwo:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to access it. How then would i update it though? I want to increase the number of likes. I tried chinTwo["likeCount"] = chinUp["likeCount"] + 1 but that gave me the error that Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'Int'

Comment: Try chinTwo["likeCount"] = (chinUp["likeCount"] as Int) + 1